# 1. java ')' expected error + 2. 'else' without 'if' error

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors, compareto

The error **')' expected** is encountered on line 8; and the error **'else' without 'if'** is found on line 9. 
This is only a part of the method. The beginning declares all needed variable (name1, name2, count), and states possible exceptions when reading the file. At this point, the program should already be reading the file in order to compare the names written in the file.

```
 while ( ! TextIO.eof() )
            do {
                name1.compareTo(name2);
                if (name1.equals(name2));
                count++;
            } while ( ! TextIO.eof() );





    if (count >= 0){
        System.out.println("You encountered" + count "identical names.");
    else
        System.out.println("There was no name encountered more than once.");
    }
```

Comment: It's very unclear why you've labelled *part* of your code as a Javascript snippet (which it isn't) and then got other code after it.

Comment: Close `}` before `else` and open a new one after it, i.e. `} else {`

Comment: `+ count "identical ` you forgot a `+` after the `count`

Comment: this question is wrong and out off topic and should not be answered :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end of the `if` statement.  The `;` ends the `if` statement.

```
if (name1.equals(name2))
count++;
```

And add braces for `if` and `else` separately.

```
if (count >= 0)
{
    System.out.println("You encountered" + count + "identical names.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("There was no name encountered more than once.");
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain the first error: **')' expected**

Comment: For the **')' expected** I was missing a "+" after "count" like someone here suggested. And for the second error, the brackets were not at the right place. Both errors have been corrected. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count >= 0){
    System.out.println("You encountered" + count "identical names.");
else
    System.out.println("There was no name encountered more than once.");
}
```

Should be changed to

```
if (count >= 0){
    System.out.println("You encountered" + count "identical names.");
} else {
    System.out.println("There was no name encountered more than once.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you must delete **;** from end of if statement , that is it .